# How do I implement the TabIndex on a user control

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I use several user controls, along with standard ASP.Net controls, to build my webform. Standard controls have a TabIndex property that lets me control the sequence in which the controls receive focus. Can I implement this for my user controls?
My user controls are visually simple and look like a standard textbox or dropdown list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just create a public property on your usercontrol that gets/sets the tabindex property on the ui control (Textbox etc..) that you want it to affect.

Edit: if you call the property "TabIndex" you will have to declare it override